# Postgres JSON Array data processing

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

Have a table "json_test" and inserted the following record:

```
create table json_test ( v json);

insert into json_test values ('{"facilityId": ["20","30","40","50","51"]}')

SELECT trim(json_array_elements_text(v->'facilityId') ) from json_test
```

The above select lists the facility ID as individual rows.

I need the same rows in a Postgres function to insert the record into another table. I wrote the following code to return `i`. The output of the `v_status` when checked is `(20,,,,,,,,,,,,)`. I need to get just `20`, but I am unable to get that.

```
for i in SELECT json_array_elements_text(v->'facilityId') from json_test

loop

v_status:=  i;

end loop;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified entire function definition in your question. 
Assuming you have DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE json_test(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  v JSON
);

INSERT INTO json_test(v) VALUES
  ('{"facilityId": ["20","30","40","50","51"]}'::JSON);
```

You can check full [**PL/pgSQL guide**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql.html) as a reference, but your function may be defined as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_facility_ids(rid INTEGER)
  RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  t TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR t IN SELECT json_array_elements_text(v->'facilityId')
    FROM json_test WHERE id = rid
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT t;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT get_facility_ids(1) AS facultyId;
```

**Just for your information**, you can `INSERT` records from `SELECT` statements. Check the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).